# PHP MySQLi prepared statement fetch() returns '1' instead of result from query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

When I execute the following code on a server that does not support get_result(), $results comes back as '1'. It seems that $stmt->fetch() is not working properly. Is there something I am doing wrong?

I am using a GoDaddy Shared Hosting Account and my local server as my testing environment. My local server supports get_result() so that works as intended.

```
$stmt = self::$conn->prepare($sql);

$ex = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();

if (method_exists($stmt, 'get_result'))
{
    $results = $stmt->get_result();
}
else
{
    $results = $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Comment: If you var_dump($results) is it an int(1) or is it something else? If you want an associative array you should also pass in the fetch_style like so $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

Comment: var_dump returns BOOL(true). also, $stmt->fetch() does not accept parameters.

Comment: Ohh my bad, I thought this was PDO::fetch()

Comment: What are you doing wrong is ignoring manual entry for the function you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to solve my issue:

```
$stmt = self::$conn->prepare($sql);

$ex = $stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();

$results = array();
$allResults = array();
$params = array();

$meta = $stmt->result_metadata();
if ($meta)
{
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    {
        $allResults[$field->name] = null;
        $params[] = &$allResults[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);
}

while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $results[] = $allResults;
}

$stmt->free_result();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although PHP codebase is indeed inconsistent, there is still very little sense in having two different functions for returning the same value. So, we can conclude that fetch() returns not the same thing as get_result(). Having concluded that we can verify our assumption using manual page. And find there the right usage for the fetch()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bind result for the fetch() if this is mysqli

```
 /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $code);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_stmt::fetch` returns a bool value and they don't accept any parameters. You can clearly see it in documentation. If you need to pass sql statement then `mysqli_stmt_fetch` is your function which accepts `mysqli_stmt` as an argument.

You should use

```
 $stmt->bind_result($field1, $field2);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
     $result[] = array($field1,$field2);
    }
```

You can find more info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)